# Add UI Controls to a custom TableView cell in code

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have created a custom cell for my TableView to show 1 ~ 5 rows of information in each cell. So, I have to create UILabels and UISwitches for each row of data in code, and Add them as subViews to my custom cell.
I tried to add UI Controls in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method before returning the custom cell with no success. Tried to add a `viewDidLoad` method in my customCell.m file and create controls in it, but UITableViewCell does not have a `viewDidLoad` method. 
Where should I create UIs and how can I add them to customCell?

Comment: You can either subclass a UITableViewCell and paint your custom cell through Interface Builder, and add this custom cell subview into your tableview via cellForRowAtIndexPath. Alternatively, in cellForRowAtIndexPath, you may use your code to define your cell directly. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this if you subclassed UITableViewCell:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
```

And add UI elements to self.contentView as subviews while you are in this function.

Comment: I was able to add subviews to custom cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, before returning the cell, but when I add the same code to `initWithStyle` method nothing happens!

   
`UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 10, 240, 30)];
    myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.0];
    myLabel.text = @"test.email@gmail.com";
    myLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    [self.contentView addSubview:myLabel];

    return self;`